# Taking EOF as input in C .

Tags: c

I want to print the value of EOF in C .

```
char ch =getchar() ; 
printf("%d",ch) ;
```

this correctly prints the value -1 when I type in CTRL + Z (I am working in windows).

While.

```
char ch ;
scanf("%c",&ch) ;
printf("%d",ch) ;
```

incorrectly prints 126 .

What is the reason for this unusual behaviour ?

Comment: What value does `sscanf` return? It likely returns 0 or EOF, in which case the value of `ch` is undetermined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EOF is intended to be distinguishable from any value that could be contained in the file being read.

As such, when you're reading from a file, and might receive an EOF, you should *not* use a `char` to hold that value. You should use an `int`, and only convert the result to `char` *after* you've verified that what you received was *not* an EOF. To get correct results, try something like this:

```
int char;
ch = getchar();
printf("%d", ch);
```

For your second example, when you read data with `scanf`, you find out how much (if any) data is read by checking its return value. If it encountered the end of a file, it will simply stop trying to convert input, and you'll find out how many fields were successfully converted by checking its return value. It won't try to convert EOF into a variable.

Answer (score 2):

You haven't checked the return value from scanf. I'll bet it was zero: no patterns matched.

The value "126" is the uninitialized value of `ch`.

---

Edit: on closer inspection of [the man page](http://www.manpagez.com/man/3/scanf/) the return value should be `EOF`. Note that that's the *return* value, not the value written to `ch`.

Comment: How do I check the return value of scanf ? Please forgive me for a silly question , I  am a noob in C programming .

Comment: The return value comes out to -1 . 
    char ch ;
    int n = scanf("%c",&ch) ;
    printf("the return value is  %d\n",n) ;
    printf("%d",ch) ;

Comment: So, according to [the documentation](http://www.manpagez.com/man/3/scanf) (you did read that, right), it returns zero if it didn't match anything, or `EOF`, at the end of the file (ok, I didn't know that one). Did you check what the numeric value of `EOF` is on your system? I'm guessing `-1`.

Comment: So, there you have your answer: EOF is not returned in `ch` because `scanf` returns it a different way.

Answer (score 1):

What gave you the idea that scanf would fill in a character argument with EOF?

The scanf function hit EOF and it fails to do the conversion and it returns. The value of ch is whatever random value was on the stack when you declared the variable.

Answer (score 1):

You should check the return code of scanf, it should return EOF. In this case your char is not affected, and because uninitialized might be 126